# Webtrends- iOS SDK (3.0.14) response code 500

Tags: ios, swift2, ios9, webtrends

I am using `Webtrends` - iOS SDK (3.0.14) in my `Swift` application and configured `wt_dc_dcsid` in `webtrends.plist`.
It is working fine two or three times  application launched but after some time getting response error.

> Response code: 500

Please find the below response for more information.

```
Response body: {"valid":false,"message":"Internal Server Error","events":[]}
```

If I can delete app and reinstall webtrends SDK working but after some times getting response error.

Does anyone knows why?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The Webtrends-Backend has problems with special characters, like "ü" in my case. I always got a response code 500 when sending data containing a "ü".
That might be the problem in your case as well.

Answer (score 0):

Webtrends-Backend has problems with special characters, like "ü" please convert you parameter whatever you are passing by below code-

let videoTitletring = wtVideoTitle.addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters: .urlHostAllowed)